# SOCKS proxy server for Windows

Tags: windows, proxy

I am looking for a program that can:

- provide a [SOCKS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOCKS) proxy server
- support Windows 7
- require no or little configuration

Answer (score 8):

[3proxy](http://3proxy.ru/). Very small console program, can do a lot. Free & opensource, cross platform. A proxy server is created with an 1 line config.

Comment: Nice, it's free and open source (and still maintained)!

Comment: Any idea why Firefox says "This web page at 3proxy.ru has been reported to contain unwanted software and has been blocked based on your security preferences." ?

Comment: Chrome does not flag it.

Comment: @Moab: it happens when you click on the download link inside that page, not on the page linked by OP directly

Comment: @user1338062: If you ignore the warning, you'll get the hint that "Few antiviral products inadequately detect 3proxy as Trojan.Daemonize, Backdoor.Daemonize. 3proxy is not trojan or backdoor and contains no functionality except described in documentation. Clear explanation of this fact is given in [Microsoft article](https://www.microsoft.com/security/portal/threat/encyclopedia/entry.aspx?Name=Program%3AWin32%2FTinyProxy)."

Comment: That Microsoft article states: "Program:Win32/TinyProxy is a detection for a proxy server program also known as "3proxy". This program was detected by definitions prior to 1.149.1596.0 as it violated the guidelines by which Microsoft identified unwanted software. Based on analysis using current guidelines, the program does not have unwanted behaviors. Microsoft has released definition 1.149.1596.0 which no longer detects this program."

Comment: And you're all ignoring the fact that it's trying to access a _Russian_ website.

Comment: @jiveturkey what "it"? 3proxy? And what if the site is russian? Then stop using `nginx`, it's russian too (made by a Rambler employee).

Comment: @user1338062 Explanation on 3proxy.ru: *"Few antiviral products inadequately detect 3proxy as Trojan.Daemonize, Backdoor.Daemonize, etc and many detect 3proxy as a PUA (potentially unwanted program). It may cause browser warning on download page. 3proxy is not trojan or backdoor and contains no functionality except described in documentation. Clear explanation of this fact is given in Microsoft. article. "*

Answer (score 6):

You can use [CCProxy](http://www.youngzsoft.net/ccproxy/):

- non-free
- support Windows 7
- provides SOCKS v5 server:

[image]

- nothing to be configured except allowing the IP of the clients:

[image]

[image]

- support many other protocol:

[image]

To connect to it, e.g., in Firefox:

[image]

Comment: Looks like it doesn't run as service.

Comment: @Hikari: Not by default but if you click on "Options" then you'll see an tickbox labelled "NT service".

Answer (score 4):

[**WinGate**](http://www.wingate.com/) has had SOCKS support for many years.  The current version supports:

- SOCKS4
- SOCKS4a
- SOCKS5, including support for UDP, and plaintext and GSSAPI (Active Directory integrated *) authentication

Policy/Events support allows you to modify Connect, Bind and UDP associate requests, so you can divert connections where you like.

Connections can be intercepted to other proxies (for example the caching web proxy, or mail proxies) so that HTTP (and even HTTPS) over SOCKS can benefit from caching and AV scanning.

Connections can also be gatewayed via an upstream SOCKS4, SOCKS4a or HTTP tunneling proxy.

WinGate has a free license for 10 concurrent users or you can purchase a license if you need more users or features.

[Feature Breakdown by license](http://www.wingate.com/products/wingate/licensing.php)

* You need an enterprise license for AD support.

Disclaimer: I work for Qbik, the authors of WinGate

Answer (score 1):

Another more simple solution is [FearGate](https://gate.feardc.net) - fast and easy to use **SOCKS5**, **SOCKS4** and **HTTPS** proxy server, **TCP** and **UDP** protocol port mapper using **IPv4** and **IPv6**. Supports access restrictions and traffic monitor. Number of running servers is **unlimited** as long your resources can handle.

**Demo** is available for testing, uptime is limited to **30 minutes**. Unlimited version **single user lifetime license** price is **50€**.

Screenshots:

[image: Proxy server]

[image: Port mapper]

[image: Access restriction]

[image: Traffic monitor]

[image: Settings manager]

[image: About FearGate]