# Easy-to-setup VPN server?

Tags: gratis, windows-7, vpn-server

I want to create a small VPN server on my Windows computer, for personal use.

No complex features needed. Just browsing the web from outside, using my home's IP address.

Requirements:

- Easy to setup, even for a person who has no experience with VPN
- Simple user interface
- Clear instructions that can be easily followed
- Runs on Windows 7
- Free

Comment: If a proxy server is enough: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/4012/903 . Also can you please mentioned the VPN servers you tried if any that you consider to hard to set up?

Answer (score 3):

Since [LogMeIn Hamachi](http://www.logmein.com/) isn't [free anymore](http://www.engadget.com/2014/01/21/logmein-ditches-free-accounts/), you can use [OpenVPN](http://openvpn.net/):

- free and open source
- [Instructions to set up the server are clear and can be pretty easily followed](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Easy_Windows_Guide)
- Runs on Windows 7

[image]

Note that if you just want to do tunneling and don't care about the UDP packets (see [VPN Tunnel vs SSH Tunnel](https://superuser.com/q/436485/116475)) you can use a [SOCKS proxy server](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/4012/903).

Comment: The instructions do not look *that* easy ;-) I guess the asker is looking for a graphical wizard.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [SoftEther VPN](http://www.softether.org/).

> SoftEther VPN ("SoftEther" means "Software Ethernet") is one of the
>   world's most powerful and easy-to-use multi-protocol VPN software. It
>   runs on Windows, Linux, Mac, FreeBSD and Solaris.

It is free and open source.

[Installation instructions for Windows](http://www.softether.org/4-docs/1-manual/7._Installing_SoftEther_VPN_Server/7.2_Install_on_Windows_and_Initial_Configurations)

[image: SoftEther VPN]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx):

- free for private use
- supports all major protocols (RDP, RemoteFX, IPsec, L2TP)
- XP, Vista, Windows 7 and Mac OS X

Comment: to OP: Please note that TeamViewer has different connection concept – it is dependent on central TeamViewer server. Advantage: your VPN server does not need external IP address. Disadvantage: if central server is down, you cannot connect your VPN (it happened to me alreday more than once). Also please note that TeamViewer for commercial use is about 900€ per channel. Channel roughly means that one PC has opened one or more TeamViewer connections. If your VPN will be partially used for making money, consider OpenVPN + leasing of external IP address or prepare for TeamViewer purchase.

Comment: Do you mean that if TeamViewer is installed on my computer, I can easily allow my friend to a use my IP address (let's say my friend is in Turkey and I want to give her access to my uncensored Internet)? If yes, would you mind explaining in what menu/etc I can enable that and what info I should give to my friend? Thanks a lot!

Comment: With TeamViewer, your friend can "log in" to your PC and effectively take control. She sees your desktop, just as you do (in a window on her PC, which can be full-screen), and use her mouse and keyboard to control it, as if she were sitting in front of it. Note that this gives her full access to your PC. She can also transfer files to/from it.